# Flutter Firestore - NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Okay. I've been using Flutter for a little more than a year now. I've been using this same code in almost every app, and it works. For some reason, it doesn't work in this new app that I'm building.

```
String testString(DocumentSnapshot doc, String val) {
  try {
    if (doc == null) {
      return "error! DB not found!";
    }
    if (doc[val] == null) {
      return "'" + val + "' doesn't exist in DB";
    }
    return doc[val];
  } catch (e) {
    return "Error: something went wrong";
  }
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
String testUndString(DocumentSnapshot doc, String val) {
  try {
    return doc != null ? (doc[val] != null ?  doc[val] : "undefined") :  "undefined";
  } catch (e) {
    return "Error: something went wrong";
  }
}
```

and this:

```
String testUndString(DocumentSnapshot doc, String val) {
  try {
    return doc.data != null ? (doc[val] != null ?  doc[val] : "undefined") :  "undefined";
  } catch (e) {
    return "Error: something went wrong";
  }
}
```

After doing some searching, it looks like I've done this correctly, but it still returns the error:

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if (doc is !DocumentSnapshot) {
    return "error! DB not found!";
}
```